# Joint distribution of random variable and its cdf.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Let $Y:=(X,F_X(X))$ where $X\sim F_X$ and $Y\sim F_Y$. Naturally using the probability integral transform I know that the marginal distribution of the second variable in Y is standard uniformly distributed so I define $U:=F_X(X)$. Now, intuitively I would say that
$$F_{X|U=F_X(x)}(x) = P(X\leq x|U=F_X(x))=P(X\leq x)=F_X(x),$$
but how would I go about proving it?

Comment: My intuition does not quite align with yours. For instance if $F_X$ is strictly increasing, then $U = F_X(x) \Leftrightarrow X = x$, so 
$$P(X ≤ x | U = F_X(x)) = P(X≤x | X= x) = 1$$

Comment: @JensKramer . You've assumed that $X$ is independent of $U$.  Why?

Comment: That is a good question, I see now where my mistakes are.